# ES6 promise has never type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have an if condition where I am checking whether a variable is a promise:

```
if (!(myVar instanceof Promise) && !myVar.then) {
    // do something...
}
```

Here for some reason typescript throws an error saying `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'never'`. In other words, typescript is considering my variable `myVar` to be of type `never` in the second `if` predicate i.e. `!myVar.then`.

Also when I change the if condition to the following:

```
if (!myVar.then && !(myVar instanceof Promise)) {
    // do something...
}
```

Everything seems to work fine.

Why is this happening? Any help would be appreciated

Typescript playground examples:

- With the `then` error:

  ```
  let myVar = new Promise(() => { })

  if (!(myVar instanceof Promise) && !myVar.then) {
      console.log('')
  }
  ```
- Without the `then` error:

  ```
  let myVar = new Promise(() => { })

  if (!myVar.then && !(myVar instanceof Promise)) {
      console.log('')
  }
  ```

Comment: your logic **will always test** for `myVar.then` - except if `myVar` **is** an instanceof `Promise` - is that what you want?

Comment: I only want to check whether the variable is a promise or not. I am aware that only checking `myVar.then` should suffice for my case. I am asking this question out of curiosity. I cannot understand why the thing that is happening, is happening

Comment: In general, it's a horrible idea to have things that are promises some times and not other times.

Comment: @NahushFarkande - I understand that, but I don't understand which bit of code would issue that error - because there is no error in any of it - the only way your code would produce an error is if you run `myVar.then(....)` inside the if condition

Answer (score 0):

It's control flow analysis together with type guards at work. It figured out that the branch after `&&` will never get executed, because in your code `myVar` is **always** a `Promise`, and it expressed that by assigning `never` type to `myVar` in that branch.

Rejecting benign extra condition with such an error may seem too strict, but in other cases it helps catch real errors. Also, the error goes away once you have correctly-typed code that could potentially go through either branch (however, control flow analyzer could become smarter in the future and start rejecting this code too):

```
let x: boolean = true;
let myVar = x ? new Promise(() => { }) : { then: false };

if (!(myVar instanceof Promise) && !myVar.then) {
                                   // no error
    console.log('z')
}
```